# Как получить реальный IP-Адрес компьютера в локальной сети (Java)

Tags: java, сеть, ip

Я пытаюсь получить IP-Адрес компьютера в локальной сети, используя следующий код:

```
try {
  hostAddress = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
} catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
  //...
}
```

На моём ПК установлен VirtualBox, и при запуске программы получаю IP-Адрес виртуальной машины:
[image]
Как исправить? Заранее спасибо!)

Comment: Если ваша программа выполняется в VirtualBox, то это и есть реальный IP адрес ее хоста.

Comment: Да в том то и дело, что программа запускается на реальной машине...

Answer (score 0):

В одной из программ я получал ип таким образом. Не помню точно почему так, но там нужно отсеивать виртуальные интерфейсы.

```
public static String getLocalIpAddress() {
        String ip = "";
        try {
            Enumeration<NetworkInterface> interfaces = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
            while (interfaces.hasMoreElements()) {
                NetworkInterface iface = interfaces.nextElement();
                // filters out 127.0.0.1 and inactive interfaces
                if (iface.isLoopback() || !iface.isUp() || iface.isVirtual())
                    continue;


                Enumeration<InetAddress> addresses = iface.getInetAddresses();
                while (addresses.hasMoreElements()) {
                    InetAddress addr = addresses.nextElement();
                    if (addr instanceof Inet4Address) {
                        ip = addr.getHostAddress();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return ip;
    }
```

Comment: Всё равно возвращает адрес виртуальной машины. Может моё приложение действительно запускается через виртуалку... Но вроде нет, что через IDE, что через .jar - ему хоть бы хны...

Comment: @Dev0ps попробуйте в дебаггере посмотреть чем отличается нужный вам интерфейс и тот, который оно выводит. Отличия должны быть, но я не могу сказать какие именно. Для меня этот метод работает хорошо, на виндоус, линукс, макос и даже под виртуалками. МОжет я тоже что-то упустил, если у вас такая проблема

Comment: На самом деле мне нужен IP компьютера в локальной сети Wi-Fi. И я попробовал проверить интересный способ: получить NetworkInterface по имени, указав следующее как "wlan0". И о чудо, реальный интерфейс Lan беспроводной сети получен, и следственно искомый IP... Но боюсь, не будет ли данное решение костылем))